# Reading a length of a string, then inverse/reverse the string

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Basically, I have managed to write this, and I managed to reverse a single word! But when I try to reverse a string that contains 2 or more words, I cant get the output. Anyone know how to solve this, or perhaps some tips?

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
      char words[100];
      int x, i;

      cout<<"Enter message : ";
      cin>>words;

      x = strlen(words);
      //This two line is used to reverse the string
      for(i=x;i>0;i--)
         cout<<words[i-1]<<endl;

     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using C strings if it's supposed to be a C++ assignment ?

Comment: Why don't you use `string`? Change `char words[100]` to `string words` and change `x=strlen(words)` to `x=words.length()`

Comment: Also, `cin >> words` will stop parsing at the first whitespace character. You'll need to use something like `getline()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with char array vs std::string - it's with the input method.

Change `cin>>words` to `cin.getline(words, sizeof(words), '\n');`

I'm guessing this task is an assignment to get used to arrays, so stick with char array - otherwise, yes, std::string is the way to go for ease of use.

Comment: dude, thanks! you're a lifesaver. my lecturer never thought me this "getline" things. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::string` instead of C char array, also can use string::reverse_iterator read words with reverse order. To read multiple words separated by space, you need to use std::getline.

```
std::string words;
std::getline(std::cin, words, '\n'); //if you read multiple words separated by space

for (string::reverse_iterator iter = str.rbegin() ; iter != str.rend(); ++iter)
{
  std::cout << *iter;
}
```

or use `std::reverse`

```
std::reverse(words.begin(), words.end());
```

Comment: The problem in your code is int that cin operator >> reads only one word from stream.

Answer (score 0):

use `cin.getline(words,99)` insted of `cin>>words` because cin>>words will get the char array only upto the first white space.